# Error while Parsing Sentence in Python Using stanford-corenlp-full-2014-10-31

Tags: python, parsing, stanford-nlp

I am trying to parse a sentence using standford corenlp in python and while Parsing Sentence I am getting following error,

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py3.4.egg\nltk\parse\api.py", line 45, in parse
    return next(self.parse_sents([sent]))
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

Following is my script:

```
import os
from nltk.parse import stanford
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = 'D://735199//jar//pythonJars'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = 'D://735199//jar//pythonJars'

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="D://735199//python//packages//stanford-corenlp-full-2014-10-31//edu//stanford//nlp//models//lexparser//englishPCFG.ser.gz")

sentences = parser.parse(("Hello, My name is Melroy.", "What is your name?"))
print(sentences)

# GUI
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence.draw()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `parse` can accept multiple sentences like that? What happens if you pass in only one?

Comment: Thanks, But its still not working when I keep just 1 sentence. I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentences = parser.parse(("Hello, My name is Melroy.", "What is your name?"))
```

You're passing in a tuple here rather a list that parser.parser() expects.